# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in helpers.php 233

Tags: laravel-5.5

When I create a new Laravel project, the browser displays an error 500. I found this in the log:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233

the code in 233 is:

```
return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);
```

But as i know, null coalescing operator( `??` ) is supported from PHP 7.0

My PHP Version:

PHP 7.1.8-2+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2017 14:34:05) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.8-2+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Laravel Version: 5.5.0

Who knows what happened?

Comment: checking php version for me worked (had on 5.x, need 7.x)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say you installed the PPA 7.1.8 as CLI only (php7-cli). You're getting your version info from that, but your libapache2-mod-php package is still 14.04 main which is 5.6. Check your phpinfo in your browser to confirm the version. You might also consider migrating to Ubuntu 16.04 to get PHP 7.0 in main.

Comment: i completed purge all php 5.6 and 7.1, and reinstall 7.1, than everything is ok, thanks.

Comment: Worked for me. Update php version on the server and everything is working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me lots of frustration.  I really hate these server config details, it is a fate almost worse than death.

Comment: Awesome, just changed my PHP version in WAMP :D

Comment: Works for me too in windows, WAMP

Comment: i am using php 7.2.1 (cli), but it still showing this error

Comment: @asifsharifshahid check the version through your web server SAPI. Make a php page with phpinfo(); and nothing else, then pull it up.

Comment: i installed the latest wamp server and the latest laravel and i faced this problem. got stressed for two days and i didn't notice my active php version until i landed here. i quickly change it from 5.6.35 to 7.2.4 and problem solved.
thanks

Comment: Yeah, Changing the PHP version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 17):

I had approximately the same problem with Laravel 5.5 on ubuntu, finally i've found a solution [here](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/#) to switch between the versions of php used by apache :

1. **sudo a2dismod php5**
2. **sudo a2enmod php7.1**
3. **sudo service apache2 restart**

and it works

Comment: Please tell me how to deals with same problem for cpanel server?

Answer (score 1):

If you came across this error while using the command line its because you must be using php 7 to execute whatever it is you are trying to execute. What happened is that the code is trying to use an operator thats only available in php7+ and is causing a syntax error.

If you already have php 7+ on your computer try pointing the command line to the higher version of php you want to use.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/[php-7-folder]/bin/:$PATH
```

Here is the exact location that worked based off of my setup for reference:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5-7.1.4-20170506-100436/bin/:$PATH
```

The operator thats actually caused the break is the "null coalesce operator" you can read more about it here:

[php7 New Operators](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2015/07/php7-new-operators/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have newly upgraded your php version you might be forget to restart your webserver service.

Comment: I agree with you. After upgrade php version please make sure to restart the webserver service (apache/tomcat/iis n etc) .

Comment: php -v on cmd(windows) and phpversion() was showing the correct version but somehow git bash terminal on vs code showing previous version and ?? operator was showing as error. The problem is resolved after restarting windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and the problem is that I had not correctly installed Composer.

I am using Windows and I installed `Composer-Setup.exe` from [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and when you have more than one version of PHP installed you must select the version that you are running at this point of the installation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the laravel initiation. The solution was as follows.

1st - I checked the version of my PHP. That it was 5.6 would soon give problem with the laravel.

2nd - I changed the version of my PHP to PHP 7.1.1. ATTENTION, in my case I changed my environment variable that was getting Xampp's PHP version 5.6 I changed to 7.1.1 for laragon.

3rd - I went to the terminal / console and navigated to my folder where my project was and typed the following command: php artisan serves.
And it worked! In my case it started at the port: 8000 see example below.

C: \ laragon \ www \ first> php artisan serves
Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

I hope I helped someone who has been through the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of problem. It looked like this:
[image: Laravel error]

Null coalescing operator( ?? ) is not supported by my version of PHP. As I had no option to upgrade the version, I wrote something like this: `{{ $product->price ? $product->price:'' }}` instead of  `{{ $product->price ?? '' }}` and it solved the problem.