# Installing php7 or newest version on ubuntu 14.0

Tags: php

firstly, i've installed php5 on my system, and i want to upgrade to php7.1 and 
and then I download the source code from the official website, and I install it.

The installation process was success, when I checked with `php -v`, it displayed `php7.1`
But when I check with phpinfo(), it's still displays the oldest php version

how can it happen where there are two different php versions but not stack each other `PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22`

Now, the problem is how to use the latest php7.1 on my localhost

thanks beforely, i'm sorry if my questions is unexplicit

Comment: do you use apache? nginx?

Comment: i used apache2 exactly

Comment: Did  you use this ppa : https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php ? and apt?

Comment: If php7.1 is already installed, use the ppa above, then install libapache2-mod-php7.1 and finally enable mod for php7.1

Comment: okeey, i've installed libapache2-mod-php7.1 , then what should i do next?

Comment: You now need to activate the php7.1 module and restart apache. See my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't install `libapache2-mod-php7.1` yet, install it.

then deactivate the older php module:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

and activate the new module php7.1 in apache:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

And finally restart apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: yaay , finally it's changed, but when i try to open phpmyadmin, it's going error,

Comment: yaay , finally it's changed, but when i try to open phpmyadmin, it's going to error,
the message is 

"phpMyAdmin - Error

The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration."
what caused it?

Comment: now, the message is "mysqli extension is missing " i've search on my php.ini and check it maybe mysqli extension to be commented out or not, but i didn't found anything , should i install mysqli extension again?

Comment: oh it's solved, i install it again and fixed!!, thanks a lot bro :D !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a duplicate of this question which I answered earlier this week. See the accepted solution which will fix your problem.

[PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in helpers.php 233](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233/45992741#45992741)

I also recommend just upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 or 17.10 and using the main supported version instead of a PPA. Just my two cents.

Comment: I've upgraded it before, but my laptop runs very laggy :D , so i did downgrade my OS to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: sorry sir, is there a any fault when i'm installing php7 ? should i purge the php5-common ?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove php5-common then sudo apt-get autoremove. If you have trouble with performance under 16.04 try installing the hwe kernel.