# Parse error when running cron job in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I've updated my crontab using `crontab -e` to run the Laravel task scheduler every minute. It wasn't working so I set it to add its output to a log file, like so:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/project/artisan schedule:run >> cron_output.log
```

Now the log contains the following message:

```
Parse error: parse error in /path/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233
```

This is the method it points to (I've commented next to line 233):

```
function cache()
    {
        $arguments = func_get_args();

    if (empty($arguments)) {
        return app('cache');
    }

    if (is_string($arguments[0])) {
        return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);    //line 233
    }

    if (! is_array($arguments[0])) {
        throw new Exception(
            'When setting a value in the cache, you must pass an array of key / value pairs.'
        );
    }

    if (! isset($arguments[1])) {
        throw new Exception(
            'You must specify an expiration time when setting a value in the cache.'
        );
    }

    return app('cache')->put(key($arguments[0]), reset($arguments[0]), $arguments[1]);
}
```

I don't understand this issue, as Laravel runs normally otherwise. PHP version is 7.2 (based on `php -v` and also `phpinfo()`) so that shouldn't be a problem. Is it possible that somehow the crontab is using an older version of PHP? If so how do I fix this? Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you run this job locally? Did it work? Looks like the job uses Cache and whatever you're passing in cannot be parsed.

Comment: I'm not running any particular task, it's just Laravel's deafult 'inspire' task inside the scheduler. And even if I remove that it still has the same error.

Comment: `return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1], null);`

Comment: @urfusion That makes sense but surely I shouldn't have to edit the syntax of Laravel core files?

Comment: What is the version of you laravel. Because I have not found cache function in my laravel helper file.

Comment: @urfusion 5.5.20

Comment: @urfusion Also see here: https://laravel.io/forum/laravel-55-syntax-error-unexpected-in-vendorlaravelframeworksrcilluminatefoundationhelpersphp-on-line-233 - but my PHP version is 7.2 so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233

Comment: @urfusion As I said, my PHP version (got in command line) is 7.2. In phpinfo it's also 7.2. In the PhpStorm settings panel, the "CLI interpreter" is 7.2 and the "PHP language level" is 7. So what I really want to know is why crontab is pulling some old version of PHP out of the bag.

Comment: Is your /path/to/project/ correct??

Comment: @Sohel0415 Yes. In the end I resolved it by giving the full PHP path to the cron syntax itself (instead of just "php") but I would still like to know how this problem was possible to begin with.

Comment: @jovan well if it works, congrats. Probably the reason behind your problem was the incorrect path. To execute schedule run, it needed the artisan command file of your actual project directory