# laravel on xampp got error but php artisan serve is working

Tags: laravel, parsing, laravel-artisan

laravel on xampp this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wedservice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 233

php artisan serve is perfectly working (Mac)???

Comment: Your question needs clarification

Comment: Which version of Laravel and php do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233/45992741)

Comment: You don't need to put your laravel project inside htdocs folder. Just put your project anywhere else and run `php artisan serve` and then open `localhost:8000` in browser

Comment: Ya , localhost:8000 is working ,by the way xampp also should work  but that server got error    unexpected '?' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wedservice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be permission issues ..
1)give permission to all files and folder
or
2)uninstall and re-install Xampp.give all rights

Comment: Thx Could you explain how to give permission to all files ?