# Ubuntu 16.04 - Nginx Laravel 500 HTTP error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm trying to startup a Laravel project through nginx but I'm stuck at the HTTP 500 error. I tried `sudo chmod 777 -R storage` also tried with `755`. Have already user `php artisan cache:clear`. Here is my config `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name cbattles.com www.cbattles.com;

    root /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

In my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I get the error

> 2018/03/06 20:33:16 [error] 4090#4090: *10 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?',
>   expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php
>   on line 42 PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a
>   stack frame in Unknown on line 0 PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax
>   error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php
>   on line 42 PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a
>   stack frame in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: cbattles.com, request: "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "cbattles.com"

The `storage/logs/laravel.log` states

```
[2018-03-06 18:33:16] local.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) at /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php:42)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(301): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/home/enthys/wo...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php(120): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#3 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(420): Symfony\\Component\\Finder\\Finder->depth(0)
#4 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(381): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->directories('/home/enthys/wo...')
#5 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1038): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\{closure}(Object(Whoops\\Handler\\PrettyPageHandler))
#6 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(384): tap(Object(Whoops\\Handler\\PrettyPageHandler), Object(Closure))
#7 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(334): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->whoopsHandler()
#8 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(1038): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\{closure}(Object(Whoops\\Run))
#9 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(339): tap(Object(Whoops\\Run), Object(Closure))
#10 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(314): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderExceptionWithWhoops(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#11 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(287): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->convertExceptionToResponse(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#12 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(188): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#13 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#14 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(326): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#15 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(124): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->renderException(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
#16 /home/enthys/workspace/CodeBattles/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 {main}
"} 
[2018-03-06 18:33:16] local.ERROR: Exception thrown without a stack frame {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 16): Exception thrown without a stack frame at Unknown:0)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

Comment: What is your error message? `tail storage/logs/laravel.log -n 100`

Comment: Looks like an issue with php version. What is the laravel version that you are running,? May be it requires 7.1 or higher.

Comment: Found the issue @Kamran was right. The issue was in my php version. The Laravel version requires  7.1^ and I was using 7.0

Comment: You read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I am not sure about all the specifics, but you need to update php to version 7.1+

I updated php to 7.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

Then removed the old version of php

```
sudo apt purge php7.1*
```

Then updated **/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini** file by setting

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.1-fpm.service
```

Next step is to update **/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com** file by setting the right version of fpm sock:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

Finally restarting nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```