# Laravel Project, 500 internal server error

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I developed a simple application in laravel (5.6) everything works fine on my PC (windows 10/ Xamp / PHP 7.1). but when i upload the same project to a VPS running Cent OS it gives

**with PHP 5.6** (which is expected)

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/clarionit/public_html/ambience/c/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233
```

**with `PHP` `7.0` / `7.1` / `7.2`**

500, Internal server error.

**What I have done so far?**

- Permissions for all files and folders are set to `777` (to see if that is a problem)
- Replacing `index.php` code with something simpler like `phpinfo()` works perfectly.

Ask for any more information needed, Please tell me what can be causing the `500, internal server error`.

Comment: **Duplicate of**   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, I have checked the version of php running by uploading   a phpinfo file, the version is php7.1

Comment: make it php greater than or equal to 7.1.3 and update composer and dump autoload and then check. And check the requirements of installation of laravel 5.6 [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation)

Comment: I have no idea that's why I leave this as open

Comment: @rahulsm, thanks, let me try that

Comment: Is there anything written to your laravel.log file?

Comment: @rahulsm, That did not work.

Comment: @MarkWalet, Thanks for help, but there is nothing in the log file

Comment: There could be several issues? Time for a chat?

Comment: @MarkWalet, Sure

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167087/room-for-mark-walet-and-prakhar-singh

Comment: Please provide the entire StackTrace.. Simple one line won't help.. If you get only that one line in browser then go to laravel.log, copy the contents and paste it here..

Comment: check your webserver log if laravel log is empty

Comment: @MeysamMahmoodi, laravel log is empty. nothing interesting in the server log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel 5.6 requirement should be installed in system

- PHP >= 7.1.3
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension
- Ctype PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extension

Once run these commands, I hope your problem will resolve.

```
rm -rf vendor
rm -rf storage/framework/cache/*
rm -rf storage/framework/session/*
rm -rf storage/framework/views/*
rm composer.lock
composer clear-cache
composer install
```

Comment: Thanks. Saved my client project in a panic ;)