# php 7.1.14 does not work with laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I just got started with laravel 5.6 got php 7.2.4 and latest version of laravel 5.6 which is according to docs requires PHP >= 7.1.3 , but the laravel fails , when I run `phpunit` and it thorws this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' 
in C:\laragon\www\forum\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php 
on line 233
```

and this is the line with the error:

```
return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);
```

and the problem is that php 7 does not support `??` operator so what is going on ? what version of php should I use with laravel 5.6 ?
if I fix that line I have an error on another line , should I fix all this errors by myself ? please help

Comment: Make sure your php version is 7

Comment: PHP 7 should support the "??" operator.  It's known as the null coalesce operator, see https://lornajane.net/posts/2015/new-in-php-7-null-coalesce-operator for usage.  You may need to restart apache if you recently installed PHP 7 to correct.  Also check to see what binary phpunit is running.  I'm betting still 5.

Comment: What's the result of `php -v` (assuming you run `php phpunit ...`)?

Comment: Thanks I fixed the issue , turns out the global php was 5.6

Comment: someone had answered it before check the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992741/9554016)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I installed php 7 but had php 5.6 as a global php, so php -v was returning 5.6 version , So I fixed it by going to global path and change the `C:\xammp\php` to new install : `C:\php7`