# Laravel not recognized by NAS

Tags: php, laravel

The NAS is a DS718+ model with DSM 6.1.7 system. There is a Web station installed and running allong with php 7, apache 2.4 and MariaDB. Web station is set up for Apache 2.4 as a back-end (I tryed nginx too) server and PHP 7 (php 5.6 not working either). All extension are ticked up in php settings, and there is a name based virtual host with web/app/public folder preset. All packadges are running. However, if a fresh new laravel 5.6 instalation is placed in web/app folder a 404 error appears. If an index.php with phpinfo() is inside, it works. Synology support simply replyed that Laravel packadge is not supported, but a few posts on web proves the opposite. 
What can by wrong with my settings. Thanks

Comment: Are there Laravel 404 error pages or apache 404 error pages? Since the first one will probably write something to `laravel.log`, which can help :)

Comment: this is the latest log:
[2018-05-30 07:05:22] local.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' at /volume2/web/ipscp/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:499)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Oof. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992685/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-helpers-php-233) answer, you might have installed a wrong version of php (only the cli interpreter) or not enabled Apache stuff.

Comment: #0 /volume2/web/ipscp/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(301): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/volume2/web/ip...')
#1 [internal function]: Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\\\Compone...')
#2 /volume2/web/ipscp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(300): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\\\\Compone...')

Comment: there is the php 5.6 and 7 package installed and running on nas and apache 2.4. i can check but is seems to be be a regular package

Comment: Yeah okay, but it can be that you need php 7 and you're using php 5.6

Comment: I've tried both. It's not that.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem: Laravel most probably won't fit with php7.0, it will need php7.1 or later, and there's no option to install this, at least not via package manager.

Comment: It is not listed among all packages for my nas either: https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/download/DS718+#packages